# Incorporate WHERE and GROUP BY into datetime sum MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

## My query:

I'm trying to sum the "duration" column by category:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(sum(`duration`)), '%T') AS `totalduration` 
FROM `my_custom_table`
WHERE `category` = "SLE"
GROUP BY `category`
```

The result is NULL but should be "05:00".

If I exclude the WHERE and GROUP BY, the query sums correctly:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(sum(`duration`)), '%T') AS `totalduration`
FROM `my_custom_table`
```

The result is correctly 24:00:00.

How do I incorporate WHERE and GROUP BY into my query?

## My data:

A phpMyAdmin/MySQL table consisting of a "duration" column (datetime) and a "category" column (varchar 255):

```
0000-00-00 05:00:00 | SLE
0000-00-00 00:30:00 | CLA
0000-00-00 00:30:00 | CLA
0000-00-00 00:15:00 | FOO
0000-00-00 01:45:00 | MON
0000-00-00 00:30:00 | CLA
0000-00-00 01:30:00 | MON
0000-00-00 02:30:00 | CLE
0000-00-00 01:00:00 | CLA
0000-00-00 01:30:00 | MON
0000-00-00 01:00:00 | REC
0000-00-00 00:30:00 | CLA
0000-00-00 01:30:00 | MON
0000-00-00 00:45:00 | CLA
0000-00-00 01:00:00 | FOO
0000-00-00 01:00:00 | REC
0000-00-00 01:00:00 | REC
0000-00-00 01:00:00 | MON
0000-00-00 00:15:00 | NOT
0000-00-00 00:30:00 | CLA
0000-00-00 00:30:00 | CLA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a SQLFiddle for you: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f31e6a/6/0

Query:

```
SELECT category, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(duration)))
FROM test
WHERE category = 'SLE'
GROUP BY category;
```

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE test (duration DATETIME, category TEXT);

INSERT INTO test (duration, category) VALUES
('0000-00-00 05:00:00', 'SLE'),
('0000-00-00 00:30:00', 'CLA'),
('0000-00-00 00:30:00', 'CLA'),
('0000-00-00 00:15:00', 'FOO'),
('0000-00-00 01:45:00', 'MON'),
('0000-00-00 00:30:00', 'CLA'),
('0000-00-00 01:30:00', 'MON'),
('0000-00-00 02:30:00', 'CLE'),
('0000-00-00 01:00:00', 'CLA'),
('0000-00-00 01:30:00', 'MON'),
('0000-00-00 01:00:00', 'REC'),
('0000-00-00 00:30:00', 'CLA'),
('0000-00-00 01:30:00', 'MON'),
('0000-00-00 00:45:00', 'CLA'),
('0000-00-00 01:00:00', 'FOO'),
('0000-00-00 01:00:00', 'REC'),
('0000-00-00 01:00:00', 'REC'),
('0000-00-00 01:00:00', 'MON'),
('0000-00-00 00:15:00', 'NOT'),
('0000-00-00 00:30:00', 'CLA'),
('0000-00-00 00:30:00', 'CLA');
```

And corresponding results:

```
category    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(duration)))
SLE     05:00:00
```

Comment: This works. Thanks for helping me to correctly structure my query and for introducing me to SQLFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(sum(`duration`)), '%T') AS `totalduration` 
FROM `my_custom_table`
GROUP BY `category` 
HAVING category = "SLE"
```

Comment: This outputs 13:53:20. The output should be 05:00 if you refer to the "My Data" section of my question.

Comment: The SQLFiddle also outputs 13:53:20 instead of 05:00:00. I've forked the SQLFiddle using your code for the purpose of demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f31e6a/10

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is no need to use group by because the where clause returns only one data.So you can do the following.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(sum(`duration`)), '%T') AS `totalduration` 
FROM `my_custom_table`
WHERE `category` = "SLE"
```

If it still returns null,You can do the following.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(sum(`duration`)), '%T') AS `totalduration` 
FROM `my_custom_table`
WHERE `category` LIKE "%SLE%"
```

Comment: Both approaches output 13:53:20. The output should be 05:00 if you refer to the "My Data" section of my question.

Comment: I did not notice earlier that when you want to find a specific row value from duration there is no need to sum up the total duration.Try following.

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`duration`), '%T')
FROM `my_custom_table`
WHERE `category` LIKE "%SLE%"

Comment: Output = 13:53:20.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `to_seconds()`:

```
select sum(to_seconds(duration))
```

If you want this in a time format:

```
select sec_to_time(sum(to_seconds(duration)))
```

Comment: The output is NULL. `SELECT sec_to_time(sum(to_seconds(duration))) FROM my_custom_table WHERE category = "SLE"`